# Please help to identify tree

Tags: identification

Tree about 5m high. Temperate, moderately continental climate (winters below freezing, so it can overwinter). It has these pretty flowers, but I've no clue about botany and nobody to ask. Please help.

[image: tree]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So distinctive I think it *has* to be *Cercis canadensis*:

[image: Cercis]
(*Image courtesy [Greg Hume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercis_canadensis)*)

Comment: I guess I'd never noticed the blossoms looking like that as they opened, but yes the leaves and the way the blossoms come from the 'trunk' look just like "Eastern Redbud" as I know it. Very popular in Texas at the moment. There's an old one just behind me as I type this. Already have two seedlings from last year ready for when the inevitable happens.